# Unable to push bound control changes to the dataset

Tags: vb.net, sqldataadapter

I am trying to compare the original and current value for a data bound text box. I've done a bit of research and tried a few methods but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using vb.net via Visual Studio 2012. Database is running on a SQL 2012 server and I'm using a stored procedure to provide the data.

Fill statement:

```
Me.SpGetEmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsEmployee.spGetEmployee, cboEmpId.SelectedValue)
```

My textbox is called txtLastName and txtLastname.Text is bound to spGetEmployeeBindingSource.LastName

I have a method that handles txtLastName.LostFocus so I can watch the values as follows:

```
Private Sub LastName_Out() Handles txtLastName.LostFocus

      Dim x as String
      x = "Hi" (breakpoint) 

End Sub
```

I run the app and load the data for employee Smith using the fill above. I go to the text box, change it to Jones and tab out. I hit the break point above and check the values in a Watch window:

```
me.DsEmployee.spGetEmployee(0)("LastName", DataRowVersion.Original).ToString
me.DsEmployee.spGetEmployee(0)("LastName", DataRowVersion.Current).ToString
```

Both lines show Smith as the value but on the screen you see Jones.

My research indicated that I may have to run EndCurrentEdit to push the textbox.text value down to the dataset but I've had no luck. The following are three examples of how I tried to end the current edit but so far the values stay the same and the dataset doesn't pick up the changes:

```
BindingContext(Me.DsEmployee.Tables.Item("Me.DsEmployee.spGetEmployee(0)")).EndCurrentEdit()
BindingContext(Me.DsEmployee.spGetEmployee.Rows(0)).EndCurrentEdit()
BindingContext(Me.DsEmployee).EndCurrentEdit
```

I have no doubt at all that I'm doing it wrong but I sure would appreciate a leg up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a couple of tests and actually got this working. Here is what I needed to do before testing the "Current" data row version:

```
me.SpGetEmployeeBindingSource.EndEdit()
```

Once I ran that line of code I could test for the value in DataRowVersion.Current and I could see the new value. Additionally when I check me.dsEmployee.HasChanges it returns True when it returned False without the EndEdit.